# Do the outer parens in "d = (((INT32) a) * ((INT32) b))" matter?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Are these statements equivalent in all C compilers?

```
d = (((INT32) a) * ((INT32) b));
d =  ((INT32) a) * ((INT32) b);
d =  ((INT32) a) * (INT32) b;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are equivalent. `(typecast)` is [higher priority](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than `*`.

You can just have `d = (INT32) a * (INT32) b;`

Comment: So I could even write `d = (INT32) a * (INT32) b;`?

Comment: @Andreas, yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of macros nearby, these statements are equivalent.

When macros are involved, people usually put all sorts of parenthesis around their code, for extra preprocessor safety. Since macros are not recommended, though, we can forget about this scenario by now.

In any case, I have found that a good policy is to isolate type casts in a separate row, because they usually involve the risk of potential loss of data. So in your case and assuming d is of type INT32, I would write:

```
INT32 aINT32 = (INT32)(a);
INT32 bINT32 = (INT32)(b);
d = aINT32 * bINT32;
```

Comment: @StephenCanon Thank you. I was thinking C++. I fixed my code.